# CentOS 7 Tomcat not Starting

Tags: tomcat, centos7

Trying to start Tomcat with `service tomcat start` which just redirects to systemctl. I get no errors, but in the logs it shows this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:266)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:465)
```

I've ensured that JAVA_HOME is correctly pointing at the jre. Here is the Unit file for tomcat:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: A simple Google search reveals several other possible things you should try. Do so, and then edit this question to show the results.

Comment: No offense, but if I hadn't been googling for quite awhile I wouldn't have asked. I couldn't find anything useful for this particular ClassNotFoundException, just a lot of others that didn't bear any fruit. If there's something obvious I missed, by all means point it out. Is there a particular result you were wanting to see? All I really found were issues with environment variables but changing them around leads to obviously worse errors.

Comment: `env` or `env|grep JAVA_HOME` could you find your java home?

Comment: I can't find any entry for JAVA_HOME there. I've tried setting both JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME manually before using the tomcat startup script, but to no avail. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this URL, and make corrections accordingly.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7

Comment: Actually, this is the very tutorial I followed to start. I don't know who keeps down voting on here, but thanks for at least trying.

Comment: let me know whether your issue has been solved or not ?

Comment: No, still having the same problem. I thought it maybe had to do with there being four different folders in /usr/lib/jvm ('jre', 'jre-1.8.0', 'jre-1.8.0-openjdk', 'jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-2.b15.e17_3.x86_64', and 'jre-openjdk'), but I've tried pointing JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME at every single one of them but with no luck.

Comment: Download java from below oracle site, install the rpm file, and set JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest. Kill all tomcat pids (ps -ef |grep tomcat). start it again

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html